# Create a Msg box in Notepad++ Macros

Tags: macros, notepad++

I have a macro that finds 's and replaces few strings. Below is the code. What I want Notepad++ to do is to show a message box if it doesn't find the string "_last". How to achieve this?

```
            <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
        <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="_last" />
        <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="2" sParam="" />
        <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="1024" sParam="" />
        <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1" sParam="" />
```

PS: I have found a very old [post](https://superuser.com/questions/459757/is-there-a-way-to-turn-off-popups-in-notepad-macros) where it says that an older version of  notepad++ shows a pop-up window on each step of a macro.